# Consumer is not registered: in google api

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-oauth

I tried use this api : http://www.script-tutorials.com/google-api-get-contact-list/comment-page-2/ for get list contacts. I change $sClientId with my Client ID from application, $sClientSecret with Client secret and $sCallback with Redirect URIs from my google application.
When call get_request_token I receive 400 error and response 'Consumer is not registered: 1099334166909-m...' and oauth_token not generated.

Can someone help me?

The request is:

https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthGetRequestToken?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.test1.com%2Findex.php&oauth_consumer_key=$sClientId&oauth_nonce=1115536411&oauth_signature=T%2FK5F%2BRmpiIcADqyF0B%2BCR1guBc%3D&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_timestamp=1414673535&oauth_version=1.0&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fm8%2Ffeeds